# How to change location of a windows form element in Visual Studios 2012 C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So in my `designer.xaml`, I have multiple Ellipses which I am using as custom buttons.

I want to change where the location of an Ellipse is upon the calling of an event. I know that pre-2012 there was, to the best of my recollection, a Location property which you could change from the cs code, but I'm not seeing it in 2012 and the only visible substitute is the `Margin.Top`, `Margin.Left`, etc.

properties, which apparently are return values and cannot be changed from code. So how do I change the location then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Change Ellipse  `Margin.Top` and `Margin.Left`(location) in code behind as like below example :

```
ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @Gil Guday:top and left are variables,you must put number instead top and left!